# Apps works on API 28 but not on 26

Tags: java, android

i'm new here (even if I've read a lot of topics) and I started development like one month ago with Java and Android Studio.

I post here because despite all the research I could do, I didn't find any solution. My app works fine on API 28 but not on API 26.

Here is my problem : I wanted to create a first app to gain experience for further apps. I did a game with a first activity where you have to click on play to go on the second one which is the game with some imageButton and you have to click to score points with a timer that decrease every time you score a point.

I wanted to share this game with a group of friend. They all have android phones with android 8.0 minimun. So I've choosen the minimum API level on API26 when I started the new project. It works perfectly on the virtual devices with API 26 and API 28 but so far it's just working on real phones with API28.

To solve this, I tried to get the minimum API level required down to 24. But it's not working either.

Then after some readings I tried to change the project structure in the *Project Structure=>App=>Properties* and I set Android 8.0 for the Compile SDK Version and Android 8.0 in *Flavors* => *Min SDK Version* and *Target SDK Version*

I had this error

> Android resource linking failed
>   app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>
> app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>
> app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2739: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2740: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> error: failed linking references.

Then I changed this line :

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

by

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'

And then it's working on a virtual device with API 26 and API 28 but still not working on real device with API 26.
The app starts with the first activity and when people click on play, it shuts down.

So now I don't now what to try to make it work.

Another fun facts is that when I generate the APK file to share it with friends, I do *Build => Generate Signed Bundle or APK* and I chose *APK* and then I generate the APK file. If I share it with WhatsApp Web, the ones with API 28 can only download it as a ZIP, and if I download it on my phone and then share it with WhatsApp, it works for them.

Thanks for reading.
I'm not a native english, so if there something you don't understand or need, please ask me, I'll be glad to give you anything to solve this problem :)

EDIT : Here is the code :

Main activity :

```
package com.example.taphypv123;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button jouer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.jouer=findViewById(R.id.jouer);

    jouer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Game = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Game.class);
            startActivity(Game);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Then the `Game` Activity:

```
package com.example.taphypv123;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

private Game activity;

private Integer[] boquette={
        R.drawable.imi1,
        R.drawable.imi2,
        R.drawable.imi3,
        R.drawable.imi4,
        R.drawable.imi5,
        R.drawable.imi6,
        R.drawable.imi7,
        R.drawable.imi8,
        R.drawable.imi9};        

private Integer[] hyppieState ={
        R.drawable.imia1,
        R.drawable.imia2}; 

private List<Integer> melange = new ArrayList<>();  
Integer tab[] = new Integer[melange.size()];
private TextView point;
private ImageButton imi1,imi2,imi3,imi4,imi5,imi6,imi7,imi8,imi9;

private int j=0;

ProgressBar mProgressBar;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
int time =5000;

private ObjectAnimator mAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game2);


    // Définition du timer
    mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(time,100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent MainActivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(MainActivity);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trop lent"+point.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    };


    //Définition de la barre de progression
    mProgressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar6);
    mAnimation=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgressBar,"progress",0,100);
    mAnimation.setDuration(time);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    mAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator){

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd (Animator animator){
        }
    });
    mAnimation.start();
    mCountDownTimer.start();


    this.activity=this;
    this.imi1=findViewById(R.id.imi1);
    this.imi2=findViewById(R.id.imi2);
    this.imi3=findViewById(R.id.imi3);
    this.imi4=findViewById(R.id.imi4);
    this.imi5=findViewById(R.id.imi5);
    this.imi6=findViewById(R.id.imi6);
    this.imi7=findViewById(R.id.imi7);
    this.imi8=findViewById(R.id.imi8);
    this.imi9=findViewById(R.id.imi9);
    this.point=findViewById(R.id.point);


    for(int i = 0; i<9 ; i++) {
        melange.add(i);}
    Collections.shuffle(melange);
    tab = melange.toArray(tab);

    imi1.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[0]]));
    imi2.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[1]]));
    imi3.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[2]]));
    imi4.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[3]]));
    imi5.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[4]]));
    imi6.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[5]]));
    imi7.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[6]]));
    imi8.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[7]]));
    imi9.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[8]]));


    point.setText("Points = "+j);

    imi1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CustomPopUp Custompopup =new CustomPopUp(activity);

            if (tab[0]==6) {
                Custompopup.setTextPopUp("T'as gagné !");
                Custompopup.setImPopUp(hyppieState[1]);
                mAnimation.cancel();
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                Custompopup.getButtonPopUp().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Collections.shuffle(melange);
                        tab = melange.toArray(tab);
                             imi1.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[0]]));                           imi2.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[1]]));                            imi3.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[2]]));                           imi4.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[3]]));                           imi5.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[4]]));                          imi6.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[5]]));                          imi7.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[6]]));                          imi8.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[7]]));                          imi9.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boquette[tab[8]]));
                        j++;
                        point.setText("Points = "+j);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bien joué",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Custompopup.dismiss();
                        time=time-500;
                        mAnimation.setDuration(time);
                        mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(time,10) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                Intent MainActivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(MainActivity);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trop lent "+point.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();

                            }
                        };
                        mAnimation.start();
                        mCountDownTimer.start();
                    }
                });
                Custompopup.build();
            }
            else {
                Custompopup.setTextPopUp("T'es mauvais Jack !");
                Custompopup.setImPopUp(hyppieState[0]);
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                Custompopup.getButtonPopUp().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Perdu  "+point.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Custompopup.dismiss();
                        Intent MainActivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(MainActivity);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                Custompopup.build();
            }
        }
    });
// Same code for imi2 to imi9

    final CustomPopUp Cust = new CustomPopUp(activity);

    if(j==123){
        Cust.setTextPopUp("PHY'S !");
        Cust.setImPopUp(hyppieState[0]);
        Cust.getButtonPopUp().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent MainActivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(MainActivity);
                finish();
            }
        });
        Cust.build();
    }

}
   }
```

And finally the CustomPopUp Class :

```
package com.example.taphypv123;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomPopUp extends Dialog {

private TextView TextPopUp;
private ImageView ImPopUp;
private Button ButtonPopUp;
private String message;

public CustomPopUp (Activity activity){
    super(activity, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup);
    this.message="lolilol";
    this.TextPopUp=findViewById(R.id.TextPopUp);
    this.ImPopUp=findViewById(R.id.ImPopUp);
    this.ButtonPopUp=findViewById(R.id.ButtonPopUp);
}

public void setTextPopUp (String message){
    this.message=message;
}
public void setImPopUp (int imPop){
    ImPopUp.setImageResource(imPop);
}
public Button getButtonPopUp() {return ButtonPopUp;}

public void build(){
    show();
    TextPopUp.setText(message);
}
 }
```

The layout of MainActivity is a `Constrain Layout` celui de Game is a `Linear Layout` with a `GridView` inside and the CustomPopUp layout is a `LinearLayout`
I can show you them if you need.

I add the graddle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.taphypv123"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

The fact is that it's perfectly working with the virtual device Nexus 5 API 28 and Nexus 5 API 26. So there no error or logcat I can get (alt +6 says nothing).
But when I generate the APK file, it's working perfectly on my Xperia XZ2 with Android 9.0 and the same on the phone of a friend of mine. But when I give the APK file to a friend who has a Samsung A8 with Android 8.0, the app opens correctly but when he clicks on "play" on the MainActivity screen, the apps shuts down without any error message, it just says "the apps stops to work, re-open ?".
Another is that I had made a first app, a counter that increase when you clicks on an image, and it worked well on the Samsung A8.
That's why I don't understand why it's not working but maybe it's because I use some class from API28 that are not in API26?

Thanks again :)

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion` ? If you are using this implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0', which you should do, your compileSdkVersion should be set to 28

Comment: "but so far it's just working on real phones with API28", please post what happened in 26, for example **logcat**.

Comment: Whenever an app crashes, give us the stack trace, and your code surrounding the crashed line.  We have no way of giving more than the vaguest of hints from this.

Comment: My `compileSdkVersion` is set to 28. I tried to set it at 26 with this implementation at 26 to see if it's changing anything but it does not. So i've changed it again to 28 in both case.

Comment: @GenoChen on the virtual device it works fine, but when I give the APK file to someone with API26, the app starts and when they push the button "play" it crashes.

Comment: @GabeSechan as it's working fine on the virtual device I do not have any stack trace from Android Studio, the only message I get from the real phone is something like "the app crashes, do you want do open it again?"

Comment: @Dlabarts when you say "it crashes", it's very important for you to provide the logcat. You may search for how to get logcat. Without code and logcat, nobody can help you.

Comment: @GenoChen okay then I'll find something and post it :) Sorry again, I'am a very beginner x)

Comment: @GenoChen I've edited my post, maybe it will be more clear. In android studio I do not have any problems, it's on a real device that it does not work =/ Thanks, feel free to say if there is anything missing or if I didn't really get what a logcat is, I'm always ready to learn new things :)